# How to make UnityAds appear after 3 deaths?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Right now the game shows ads each and every time the player dies. I want the ads to appear after the third death of the player. Please guide me as I am a beginner with no real knowledge of coding. Please also specify if I need to attach the script to a specific game object.

I have put the ads code below. Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject gameOverCanvas;

public GameObject Interstitial;

public int DeathCount = 0;

private void Start()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
   
}


public void GameOver()
{
    gameOverCanvas.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    
    DeathCount++;
    
}

private bool DeathCountCheck()
{


    if (DeathCount == 3)
    {
        // Reset the variable, otherwise it will increase indefinitely and the condition will not be met in the future
        Interstitial.GetComponent<InterstitialAds>().ShowInterstitial();
        DeathCount = 0;
        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

public void Replay()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if "deathCount" increases each time the player dies, then when the ad is meant to show you just check that variable and reset it appropriately.

```
// Function that checks if there were 3 deaths
private bool DeathCountCheck()
        {

            
            if (deathCount == 3)
            {
                // Reset the variable, otherwise it will increase indefinitely and the condition will not be met in the future
                deathCount = 0;
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
```

Then in the "ShowInterstitialAd" just add another condition

```
    public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady(interstitialID) && DeathCountCheck())
    {
        Advertisement.Show(interstitialID);
    }
}
```

Comment: rootpanthera I tried this in the same script but it is not working for some reason. Would you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Check if both conditions are met (Advertisement is ready and deathCount is 3). Also make sure that deathCount actually increases when player dies (or when appropriate)

Comment: I have edited the code above. This is my Game Manager Script. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: The ad does not play after the player dies more than 3 times

Comment: So it plays only once (when player dies 3 times) and then it doesn't at all?

Comment: No. It does not play at all :(

Comment: You will need to check which conditions are true, (each time when you call DeathCountCheck. Is DeathCount really 3? And then if it is, is interstitial really ready to show?